# Проблема с отправкой post запросов в android

Tags: php, java, android, post

я недавно начал изучать разработку под андроид и столкнулся с проблемой отправки пост запросов на сервер. на данном этапе нужно с приложения отправить адрес электронной почты на сервер, и если этого адреса нет в бд отправить на этот адрес случайное число. при попытке отправить запрос в приложении не происходит ничего, а в логах андроидстудио выходит:

```
    D/ViewRootImpl@654261c[MainActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 0
    D/ViewRootImpl@654261c[MainActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 1
    D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
    I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
    I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
    D/TcpOptimizer: TcpOptimizer-ON
```

в файле манифеста указал разрешения на использование интернета:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

так же в манифест добавил:

```
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

api на сервере написан на php:

```
if (isset($_POST['email'])) $email = htmlentities($_POST['email']);
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost','user','password','mydb')or die("Ошибка ".mysqli_error($link));
$query ="SELECT * FROM myTab WHERE email = '$email'";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link));
if($result){
    $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($rows==0){
      $nums=rand(10000,99999);
      $message=$nums;
      mail("$email",$nums);
    }else{
      $message="zanyato";
    }
}
echo "$message";
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

код функции отвечающей за отправку запроса и прием ответа в андроид:

```
void sendEmail(final String email){
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String output;
                try {
                    String data = URLEncoder.encode("email", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(email, "UTF-8");
                    URL url = new URL("http://myserver.php");//не https!
                    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
                    conn.setDoOutput(true);
                    OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
                    wr.write(data);
                    wr.flush();
                    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                    String line;
                    output="";
                    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                        output+=line;
                    }
                    final String qwe=output;
                    wr.close();
                    rd.close();
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(checkEmail.this,qwe,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

на сколько я понимаю запрос не может отправиться. пробовал искать решение этой проблемы но ничего не помогает.

Comment: Вот этот кусок код (`catch (Exception e) {
                }`) - это очень плохо. Вы, возможно, получаете сообщение об ошибке, но не выводите его в логи. Попробуйте в `catch` добавить `e.printStacktrace()` - возможно увидите сообщение об ошибке.

Comment: Возможно это 404 ошибка. Вам стоит использовать библиотеки для запуска запросов в сеть. OkHttp, например. Мало кто знает как решать проблемы с приведённым вами кодом, т.к. почти никто так запросы в сеть не делает. В случае либы у вас будет меньше кода (в разы) и лучше и понятнее сообщения об ошибках.

Comment: спасибо, я действительно получал ошибку, но теперь я не могу поять как ее исправить, вот что выдается при обработки исключения: `W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://myserver.ru/api.php W/System.err: at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:251) at com.example.keylib.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:45) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) W/libEGL: EGLNativeWindowType 0x71bfbc10 disconnect failed`
ошибка ссылается на строку: `BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));`

Comment: Проверьте, что вы указали правильный адрес в запросе - выведите его в логи и проверьте, что оно работает в браузере (Для Get запроса) или `curl`/Postman если это Post запрос. Также, кажется, у вас есть ненужный код `OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
                    wr.write(data);
                    wr.flush();` - может быть он мешает.

Answer (score 0):

проблема оказалась на сервере, мой хостинг провайдер сменил версию php и мой старый код оказался нерабочим.